# Return content for it to be shown - Right now nothing comes out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When I have picked my json from my controller, so when I have to write it in index.cshtml side so but when I type "`module.`" then there's nothing up around img, text or ID, etc.

by my ng-repeat will it count as I want appears as it should.

**The problem here** just in that it will not enter text and img whether it is empty or not. both my questions that appear on the page has no image but right now the picture is shown on the page.

It gives me such a helping hand to know what to write about it must be img or text or otherwise.

Opgaver.html

```
<input type="hidden" ng-init="Id='2'" ng-model="Id" />
    <div ng-repeat="module in Newslist" style="clear:both; margin:7px 0; min-height:110px; margin:5px 0;">
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <p>{{module.text}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-show="module.Img != null">
            <img class="img-responsive img-rounded mb-lg" src="img/projects/project.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Opgaver.js

```
var app = angular.module('Opgaver', []);
app.controller('OpgaverCheck', function ($scope, $http) {

    //GET 
    $scope.$watch("Id", function() {
        var url = "/opgaver/kategori/" + $scope.Id;

        $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
          $scope.Newslist = response; 
        });
    });  
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult kategori(int Id)
    {
        var db = Helpers.HelperToTables.DbValue;

        List<ListOpgave> list = db.LektionerOpgaves.Where(i => i.fk_LektionerId == Id).OrderByDescending(i => i.id).Select(x => new ListOpgave
        {
            Id = x.id,
            Img = x.LektionerOpgaveImg.value,
            Text = x.text,
        }).ToList();

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have "module.text", but in your MVC Controller, you have "Text".  They must be exactly the same including case.  Try changing "module.text" to "module.Text".  Also, make sure your Json is actually returning a list by putting breakpoints in both controllers.

Comment: I get nothing out of it .. and entering the page. After I have a right to what you said.

Comment: Are you getting anything in your MVC Controller?

Comment: It works now. It may be that I click F5 fast .. Maybe. But it works now and thanks for the help. Hope you will give a +1 for my question

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `$scope.Newslist = response.data;`

The response object has five properties and the information you want is contained in one of them. So as you have it written, `Newslist` is equal to the entire response, including the status and headers, rather than just the response data.

See the documentation on [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: So give it me no data on the page. like my repeater is empty.